# Hide or Remove back button in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

How can i remove or hide back button in the salesforce one UI. it take back me to the previous page but i don't want to give this functionality. So how can i hide or remove back button from custom VF pages and Standard detail pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature in place for removing or hiding the apps back button either in custom or standard pages in Salesforce1.

This would be a feature request which is best suited for the IdeaExchange. Please consider posting there to open this Idea up to the community to get some attention to this need!

[IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com)

I couldn't find anything there so far requesting this behavior...