# Hide or Remove back button in Salesforce1 Urgent

Tags: salesforce1-app

How can i remove or hide back button in the salesforce one UI. it take back me to the previous page but i don't want to give this functionality. So how can i hide or remove back button from custom VF pages and Standard detail pages.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following post [Hide or Remove back button in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79709/hide-or-remove-back-button-in-salesforce1) which provides the answer to your question - you can't remove it.